# Hindi kavita proper alignment/justification

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app related to hindi kavita(poems). I want the poems to be displayed in the way real poems are displayed like the image shown below

[image: Image showing a typical small poem in hindi]

Now the problem is I dont know how to use a textview to show this kind of text

Comment: Use spaces before or after text?

Comment: No the problem is the poems will change everyday and also the number of lines in the poem. And again the screen size will also keep changing. So we cannot use spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a linear layout with vertical orientation. Add a text view for each line, with `layout_width="match_parent"` and the appropriate `gravity` attribute.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

EDIT:

If you have your poem as an arraylist of strings where each element is a line of your poem, you can do:

```
//Initialise your layout in your activity onCreate()
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

//Start listening to your firebase data and put this somewhere in the callback:

// poemLines is a list of Strings you get from firebase
for(i=0; i<poemLines.size(); i++){
TextView view = new TextView(context);
view.setText(poemLines.get(i));
//set any other attributes to your textview that you want, width, height, font, etc
view.setGravity(i%2==0?END:START);
layout.add(view);
}
```

Comment: But vinay the problem is there will be lot of poems. Each day a new poem will be uploaded, so I cannot keep making different layouts for each poem

Comment: You can do it programatically. Assuming all odd lines have gravity="start" and even lines have gravity="end", you can add them while creating your activity/fragment.

Comment: I cannot add textview for each line because I dont know how many lines there will be in the poem. The poems are going to be uploaded each day from the backend. That's why I am using only one textview and using setText setting the text for it from an activity

Comment: What format are the poems going to be in? It would be ideal if each poem was an arraylist of lines.

Comment: I was just going to simply type the whole poem in the setText method. Actually the problem is I am going to fetch data from firebase that's why I cannot hardcore the code regarding number of textviews

Comment: And going by your suggestion what exactly can we accomplish using each poem as an arraylist of lines

Comment: If you have the poem as an array of strings where each element is a line of the array, you can achieve your usecase. I will edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Ok it will be very nice of u. Please edit the answer and let me check it